# nginx: regex not working in rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have `http://sample.cervo02.com`. i'm trying to get `https://cervo02.com/sample`.

**I tried  couple of redirect none of them are working.**  `rewrite ^([^.]*)$ https://cervo02.com/$1 last;` return `https://cervo02.com//`

the other one is `rewrite ^(.*).cervo02.com$ https://cervo02.com/$1 last;` return a 404 and the url is not rewritten.

any help is welcome thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite deals with URI, not URL.
try this

```
server {
  server_name ~ ^(?<subdomain>.*)\.cervo02\.com$;

  rewrite ^ https://cervo02.com/$subdomain$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: you got it right but can you add "" to the servername like that `server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[^.]*)\.?cervo02.com$";`. you got that part missing.